# Why do almost all PHP framework use "<?php echo ... ?>"

Tags: php, templates, frameworks, smarty, php-shorttags

- The PHP short tag `<?= $var ?>` has been **deprecated** for a while.
- Almost all **PHP frameworks**  **use the long form** `<?php echo $var ?>` (e.g., [symphony](http://www.symfony-project.org/), [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/), [Kohana](http://www.kohanaphp.com/))
- [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) is a famous PHP template engine which supports a shorter form `{$var}`
- Template engines (like *Smarty*) are easier for web designer

  - Editing a template shows `{$var}` instead of showing nothing (because of `<..>`)
  - **Shorter syntax** (less typing especially when `<>` are on the same key on some keyboard layout)
  - The templates are pre-compiled and cached giving nearly the same **performances**

All those points make me wonder, why do all framework seem to use the super long PHP syntax? Is there a strong point of not using a template engine like *Smarty* (except the small overhead)?

Comment: What about CodeIgniter? http://codeigniter.com/tutorials/watch/intro/

Comment: Why do you say smarty is easier for the designer? Have you seen a full blown smarty template? I have and it sucks!! I didn't understand it and neither did the designer

Comment: This is NOT about short PHP tag vs. long tag. Also Smarty3 is pretty fast, really. For most people the overhead is negligible. I believe one argument has been forgotten here. First that Smarty3 supports stuff like template inheritance, and second that when "previewing" a template in a browser you see `{$description}` displayed while if you use PHP `<?...?>` you don't see anything there. That also helps validating PHP (directly in the HTML editor). I don't say that to push Smarty3, just to point out my wonder. The best reason given so far is being more flexible and it can easily be implemented.

Comment: @AntonioCS In my experience, Smarty makes things easier because you're only dealing with display and formatting, rather than having a lot of unrelated PHP cluttering up the page.

Comment: @abeger: With a good design, you won't have "a lot of unrelated PHP cluttering up the page." If you include application logic in your templates, you're doing it wrong, regardless of what language/framework you're using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what Fabien Potencier of the Symfony framework [has to say about templating engines](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/34/templating-engines-in-php):

> Why do people still think PHP is a
>   templating engine? Sure enough, PHP
>   started its life as a template
>   language, but it did not evolve like
>   one in the recent years. If you think
>   PHP is still a template language, can
>   you give me just one recent change in
>   the PHP language which enhanced PHP as
>   a template language? I cannot think of
>   one.

He also describes the features that he looks for in a templating language:

> - Concision
> - Template oriented syntax
> - Reusability
> - Security
> - Sandbox mode

As well as some of the features that make his favorite templating language [Twig](http://github.com/mitsuhiko/twig) stand out:

> - Native template inheritance (templates are compiled as classes);
> - Solid automatic auto-escaping (with no associated runtime overhead as
>     everything is done during
>     compilation);
> - Very secure sandbox mode (white-list the tags, filters, and methods that
>     can be used in templates);
> - Great extensibility: you override everything, even the core features, by
>     bundling your own tags and filters as
>     an extension; but you can also
>     manipulate the AST (Abstract Syntax
>     Tree) before compilation. By
>     leveraging this possibilities, you can
>     even create your own DSL (Domain
>     Specific Language), targeted at your
>     application.

In the comments of the article, he says that, "It will probably be part of Symfony 2. But I first need some community feedback."

Read [the full article](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/34/templating-engines-in-php) to get his whole argument in favor of templating systems.

Comment: Why do you see so much overhead? Once compiled it's just like PHP. It's compiled only once. If you're thinking about the amount of included and read files, think again: Smarty3 which is way faster that Smarty2 has also way more files it includes.

Answer (score 15):

The thing about PHP is that it already *is* a templating language.

Smarty, as nice as it is, is added overhead.  If you don't have a good reason to use it, then why would you?  People who use backend frameworks are developers who are already familiar with PHP, so there's no reason to make them use a templating engine with a new syntax to learn on top of it.

Most frameworks are flexible enough that adding a template engine doesn't take much work.  If a framework was built that forced you to use Smarty, then it's going to be less popular, because the framework itself would be less flexible.

In regards to the "long syntax", no framework is going to hang their hat on a deprecated syntax with security issues.  It can be left up to the user of the framework if they want to use it or not (which no one should be these days), but building a core framework around short tags makes it less portable.

Comment: That article illustrates my points exactly.  The author mainly complains about long/verbose syntax and poor readability.  This isn't a big problem for most PHP developers who are used to the language.  Why add another layer of complexity to solve essentially a non-issue?  I think it's best summed up by this line from the article:  "but these enhancements are irrelevant when what you want to do is to mainly write templates."  How many projects have you worked on where you mainly write templates? If that's what you do, then yes, consider a templating engine.  Otherwise, there's not much impetus.

Comment: "This isn't a big problem for most PHP developers who are used to the language. Why add another layer of complexity to solve essentially a non-issue?"- That's the exact reason. The ones going to use the template WON'T be the programmers.

Answer (score 10):

I don't know that I would call `<?php print $foo; ?>` "super long syntax."

The fact is that short-tags aren't always enabled on servers, whereas the standard default typically is. It's safer going that route.

Answer (score 9):

Template engines like Smarty add an additional layer of processing that is not needed - they are mostly bloatware. They usually add too much additional processing for what amounts to syntactic sugar. Using a template engine when full PHP tags are available is like wearing shackles - it becomes another language with it's own quirks to learn in order to accomplish the same thing with regular PHP.

In my experience I've rarely seen a non-programmer fully or easily utilize a template engine. Take these two instances:

Smarty:

```
<select>
{foreach from=$k item=v}
 <option value="{$v.value|escape:'html'}">{$v.label|escape:'html'}</option>
{/foreach}
</select>
```

PHP:

```
<select>
<?php foreach ($k as $v) { ?>
 <option value="<?php echo htmlentities($v['value']); ?>"><?php echo htmlentities($v['label']); ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Now, the Smarty syntax may be slightly cleaner - but honestly, is anyone *except* a programmer going to be able work with either code set comfortably? Template engines add an extra layer of processing/logic without offering any major benefits.

Comment: Precisely Smarty does not make it clearer. The PHP code is exactly as easy as the smarty code. Stay true to php!!

Answer (score 3):

There are some reasons:

- They are to be deprecated from future versions of php due to security concerns.
- Some hosts disable them.

**More:**

**[Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)**

> They're not recommended because it's a
>   PITA if you ever have to move your
>   code to a server where it's not
>   supported (and you can't enable it).
>   As you say, lots of shared hosts do
>   support shorttags but "lots" isn't all
>   of them. If you want to share your
>   scripts, it's best to use the full
>   syntax.
>
> I agree that
>
> I don't buy readability as a reason at
>   all. Most serious developers have the
>   option of syntax highlighting
>   available to them.

**More**

http://terrychay.com/article/short_open_tag.shtml

Comment: The company I work in urged us not to use short tags any more because they were told that some sites have been found vulnerable because they used short tags, so we just stopped using them. The best answer can be given by a hacker about the reasons behind it, however, you can also find more info about it on google.

Comment: *"Images can be used to embed those tags..."* Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: @deceze: please see this: http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/post/67-PHP-security-exploit-with-GIF-images.html

Comment: @Sarfraz Where does that mention the security issue as it relates to short-tags? This sounds interesting.

Comment: @Sarfraz The linked issue has nothing to do with using short open tags. Interesting nonetheless.

Comment: @Jonathan, @deceze: I have updated my answer, please have a look at part about CodeIgniter.

Comment: @Sarfraz Sorry, but this article doesn't say anything about security issues either, especially with images. It even mentions the only possible security problem is that a server may output your raw PHP code if short_tags are switched off, but that's a server configuration issue that's easily checked before deployment.

Comment: @Sarfraz It still doesn't make a whole lot of sense. The code snippet has nothing to do with short open tags either, it just escapes long tags to HTML entities. And an ambiguous comment on some random code still does not explain a possible security issue. If there is an issue I'm really interested to hear more about it, but so far it just smells of cargo-cult.

Answer (score 3):

Short open tags are **not** deprecated and they will also **not** be removed in PHP6.

- [[PHP-DEV] Throwing an E_DEPRECATED for short_open_tag](http://www.mail-archive.com/internals@lists.php.net/msg44795.html)
- [[PHP-DEV] Re: Is it true that short_open_tag is deprecated in PHP 6?](http://www.mail-archive.com/internals@lists.php.net/msg41853.html)
- [[PHP-DEV] short_open_tag](http://www.mail-archive.com/internals@lists.php.net/msg34608.html)
- [Request for Comments: Improved short tags for templating](http://wiki.php.net/rfc/shortags)

The linked articles also contain lots of useful information about the topic.

Quoting [Rasmus Lerdorf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasmus_Lerdorf) (3rd link):

> Most of the arguments I have seen are basically saying `<?` is evil and it shouldn't even exist, but that isn't the current question. It does exist, and we aren't removing it, so the only real argument here is the WTF factor introduced by code that is able to enabled or disable these tags on the fly. That's the one and only valid argument I have seen. Whether or not PHP code can be validated with xmllint and whether or not `<?` is valid xml, which it obviously isn't, is completely beside the point. We all know that when you use `<?` you are not XML-compliant. And for the vast majority that's ok. […]
>
> My view is that people want templating. As much as I hate the concept, and have always been very vocal about that, people want simpler templating tags. They will even go as far as parsing files and generating PHP code on every single request in order to use `{blah}` instead of `<?php blah() ?>`. The fact that people are willing to take an order of magnitude performance hit for syntactic sugar is baffling to me, but just look at all the templating systems out there. And yes, I know there are other reasons to use templating such as restricting the feature set for untrusted template writers, etc. but you'd be surprised how many people just want to type less and have their tags be prettier. Getting these folks to switch to `<?blah()?>` is a win for performance and sanity in my book. Yes, it isn't a full victory, but it is still a win.

---

Personally, I try to avoid templating systems as I find regular PHP syntax much easier to use as a templating language that reinvents what PHP can do out of the box. With the addition of ViewHelpers, any designer shouldn't have too much trouble using regular syntax. Actually, I always found the argument, *Template engines (like [Smarty](http://nosmarty.net/)) are easier for web designer* pretty belittleing. The verbose PHP syntax might not be appealing aesthetically, but any half-brain can learn it.

Answer (score 2):

Because they don't want to include a library as huge as Smarty to make their templates a few characters shorter.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers there are a couple of things that make Smarty (and similar template engines) problematic.

The first is that you need to escape some characters in your template if you're going to put javascript in it. If your javascript is dynamically created by PHP, it gets even worse; the readability of that code goes down drastically.

The second and most important is that when you're working in a decent OO framework Smarty will severely decrease the functionality of your code. When using PHP as your template engine you can use $this within your template to call methods in the controller that's parsing the template. Not only that, but you get access to all the methods that controller has inherited. 
With smarty you lose this entire functionality because $this no longer refers to your controller. In essence, instead of accessing your entire framework from your template, you only have access to Smarty's limited functionality.

Comment: Smarty3 improved a lot that. I had a lot of escaping for JavaScript but not I don't have a single one. As for exposing your website libraries, I'd say it's bad habit. A template should be as simple as possible with everything prepared via the controller. Must easier to refactor later.